# Prompt for windows login credentials when accessing IIS web application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-authorization, asp.net-authentication

When i try to access an ASP.NET MVC web application hosted in IIS 6.0, i'm getting a windows popup that wants me to enter my windows login name and password. After entering the credentials, i can then reach the login page.

See in the below screenshot what fiddler captures when the windows login prompt pops up. What setting do i need in order to avoid this windows prompt?

[image]

Comment: Are you using Windows Authentication or Forms Authentication? Can you post your authentication section from configuration file?

Comment: In the web.config, Authentication mode is set to "Forms". In IIS in Authentication methods, i have both Enable anonymous access and Integrated windows authentication checked.

Answer (score 0):

Two options.

1) Disable Windows authentication. Enable Anonymous or Forms.

2) Edit your IE settings. Add the site into trusted sites and go to custom level, simply scroll to the bottom and "login with current username and password" button ticked. This will auto negotiate the windows login you are using into IIS as a pass thru.

Comment: Already tried option 1, it didn't resolve the issue. The application is used by thousands of people so option is out.

Comment: If option didn't stop the AD prompt, then you have a web.config entry overriding it. Check the authorisation or authorization section of the web.config for entry about windows authentication.

Comment: The authentication mode in the web.config is already set to 'Forms'. Actually the applications works in all other 3 environments accept 1.